# mysql table not deleting values

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql data table that holds user information such as name,department,extension and phone number

Now I have a delete query that deletes a user based on the extension number the admin enters.

It was working yesterday and I have not changed a thing so I have no idea what could be wrong.

According to my code it must delete the user and then display the table. Now it does all that but the user still exists.

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
require ("database.php");
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['CheckLogin'])) { header("Location: login.php"); }
if($_POST['action'])
{
    $this_user_ext =$_GET['extension'];
    // sending query
    mysql_query("DELETE FROM users WHERE extension = '$this_user_ext'")
        or die(mysql_error());
    include('maildelete.php');
    $extension=$_POST['extension'];
    header("Location: index.php");
}
?>
<center>
    <form action="" method="post">
        Enter 4 Digit Extension Number :
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="extension">
        <br>
        <h2>
            <input type="submit" name="action" value="Delete Extension">
            <br>
        </h2>
        <h3>
            <a href="index.php"> Main Menu </a>
        </h3>
    </form>
</center>
```

Comment: don't use deprecated+removed version `mysql_*`. turn to `mysqli_*` or `PDO` along with `prepared statements`

Comment: You are posting in POST method and Receiving in GET Method.

Comment: **You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)** and should really use **[Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)** instead of concatenating your queries. Specially since you're not escaping the user inputs at all!. You can use Prepared Statements when you stop using the deprecated and insecure `mysql_*`-api and start using MySQLi or PDO.

Comment: Try POST Instead of GET $this_user_ext =$_POST['extension']; Because your form method is post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You have used POST method but you are using $_GET so**

change `$this_user_ext =$_GET['extension'];` to `$this_user_ext =$_POST['extension'];`

Answer (score 0):

Inside your form's tag having a method `POST`. You're sending the `POST` request, not the `GET` request. Use this code instead `$this_user_ext = $_POST['extension'];`

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php
error_reporting(0);
require ("database.php");

session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['CheckLogin'])) { header("Location: login.php"); }



    if($_POST['action'])
{

$this_user_ext =$_POST['extension'];

    // sending query
    mysql_query("DELETE FROM users WHERE extension = '".$this_user_ext."'")
    or die(mysql_error());


include('maildelete.php');

$extension=$_POST['extension'];

header("Location: index.php");
}
?>
<center><form action="" method="post">
Enter 4 Digit Extension Number :<br><input type="text" name="extension">
<br><h2><input type="submit" name="action" value="Delete Extension">
<br></h2>
<h3>
<a href="index.php"> Main Menu </a>
</h3>
</form>
</center>
```

I hope U got it :) Enjoy..

Comment: A good answer includes an _explanation_, not just a bunch of code.